# Capacitance of a system of more than 2 conductors

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, conductors

For a system of 2 conductors capacitance is defined as the charge that would flow from one to another when connected by a wire divided by the potential difference between them which as a special case becomes $\frac{Q}{V}$ when the bodies hold equal and opposite charge.    Is this definition true?   If yes then my follow up query is how do we define capacitance of conductor systems with more than 2 conductors?   Is this somehow related to grouping of capacitors and finding equivalent capacitance?  Note:The goal of asking the question is to understand equivalent capacitance and its definition

Comment: See the Capacitance matrix in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance).

Comment: If you replace a group of capacitor with a single one such that all the other factors remains unchanged then the value of the single capacitor with which we replace the other capacitors is known as the equivalent capacitance

Comment: could you elaborate